# How to show alert message when closing a window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent closing browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333665/how-to-prevent-closing-browser-window)

I want to show an alert message "Please logout before closing the window" with an logout button, when an user tries to close the window and after clicking on logout button the window can be closed. How to achieve this?

Comment: You can't *prevent* someone from closing their browser.  You can give them a warning, which lets them continue or cancel.  Check out the onbeforeunload event.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333665/javascript-to-get-an-alert-when-closing-the-browser-window

Comment: Look to the right, next time read one of them. This is a FAQ! Use `window.onbeforeunload=function() { return 'Please save'}`

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997956/javascript-window-close-event-rather-than-unload-event-for-all-browsers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event

Answer (score 14):

Another implementation you can try:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onbeforeunload = function() {
          return "Did you save your stuff?"
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Update**

As mentioned in comment by @JohnnyFun "Starting with Firefox 44, Chrome 51, Opera 38 and Safari 9.1, generic message will be displayed for different browsers and cannot be customized".

Comment: Using this code I always see the same message in when closing tab in Chrome: "Do you want to leave this site? Changes you made may not be saved."

Comment: @R.S.K mdn mentions: "Starting with Firefox 44, Chrome 51, Opera 38 and Safari 9.1, a generic string not under the control of the webpage will be shown instead of the returned string. For example, Firefox displays the string "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved." (See bug 588292), and Chrome displays the string "Do you want to leave this site? Changes you made may not be saved"" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Answer (score 4):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Are you sure?";
 };
```

Try this it.

Comment: FAQ - no need to answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is not as such close event available in Javascript. You can give message onUnload event. But that doesn't prevent application from closing. This function will execute when user click on any link, submitting the form etc.

```
window.onunload=function(){SomeJavaScriptCode};
```

For reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp