# how to do an ajax call on window close in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, browser

Question is clear, I need to make an ajax call when user clicks on browser close button, but before closing the window.

Any possible solution for this?

I dont need any confirmation box etc. just a trigger for ajax and then close the window.

Comment: I've tried making a synchronous AJAX call when the window closes, and sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't. It seems browsers don't like JavaScript code that blocks a window from closing, except for cases like `alert` or `confirm`.

Comment: @GregBurghardt : so you say there is a chance for doing alert? I tried to do alert but it comes with confirmation box, and an error in console says alerts before onunload event are blocked :(

Comment: onbeforeunload  and beforeunload don't work ? what have you else you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

An answer from [How to show alert message when closing a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227127/how-to-show-alert-message-when-closing-a-window) should work here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      $.ajax(...);
  }
</script>
```