# how to detect the Page Close Event with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, clientscript

I have a ASP.NET web app with a MasterPage and contents page, from the MasterPage when I click a `MenuItem` to open a new aspx Page. if I want to close the new page browser tab, I want to show a popup or a dialog that alert the user that he is closing the browser tab. I dont know how to detect the close browserTab button.
I used the following code in the new aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CloseWindow() {
        alert('closing');
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

new page code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(typeof(Page), "closePage", "window.onunload = CloseWindow();");
}
```

Thanx in Advantage.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser

Comment: I think [this][1] is your answer.
You can provide a confirmation as well.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997956/javascript-window-close-event-rather-than-unload-event-for-all-browsers

Answer (score 4):

This works perfect.

[javascript detect browser close tab/close browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser)

```
<body onbeforeunload="ConfirmClose()" onunload="HandleOnClose()">

var myclose = false;

function ConfirmClose()
{
    if (event.clientY < 0)
    {
        event.returnValue = 'You have closed the browser. Do you want to logout from your application?';
        setTimeout('myclose=false',10);
        myclose=true;
    }
}

function HandleOnClose()
{
    if (myclose==true) 
    {
        //the url of your logout page which invalidate session on logout 
        location.replace('/contextpath/j_spring_security_logout') ;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Attribute 'onbeforeunload' is not a valid attribute of element 'body'(XHTML 1.0 Transitional)

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of problems with this myself and the only thing that works is: "window.onbeforeunload" event from javascripts but the problem is this gets executed a lot more than when you'd expect. So basicly if your working with a master page etc I don't think it can be done.

I think it's best you try to approach this differently because else your closing message will show up to often.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this with javascript in your page.
First create a function:

```
function closeMessage() {
    return "Are you sure you want to leave this page";
}
```

After that assign this method:

```
window.onbeforeunload = closeMessage;
```

Please let me know if was helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the event for closing the browser and use it to do whatever you wanna do. Here is the code that worked for me.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
          window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
               var e = e || window.event;
               if (e) e.returnValue = 'Browser is being closed, is it okay?';//for IE & Firefox
               return 'Browser is being closed, is it okay?';// for Safari and Chrome
           };
        </script>
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, you want to know when a tab/window is effectively closed. Well, afaik your only way in Javascript to detect that kind of stuff are onunload & onbeforeunload events.
Those events are also fired when you leave a site over a link or your browsers back button. So this is the best answer I can give, I don't think you can natively detect a pure close in Javascript. Correct me if I'm wrong here.you can go through [browser-tab-close-detection-using-javascript-or-any-other-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941354/browser-tab-close-detection-using-javascript-or-any-other-language)