# Trigger ajax call while closing the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to trigger an method while closing the window. For that I tried to put an alert statement and it is working **fine both in IE and FIREFOX** . ***But not working in chrome***. Please help me on this..

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
   alert ("before unload")
});
```

Comment: check this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626059/window-onbeforeunload-in-chrome-what-is-the-most-recent-fix

Comment: you can check for `useragent` and execute the relevant code block.
or check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997956/javascript-window-close-event-rather-than-unload-event-for-all-browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. There's no way in modern browsers to reliably do a non instant operation on the `beforeunload` event (especially, all operations involving a query are usually prevented). It's a security measure : nothing that may delay or prevent the user-required closing of a window is acceptable.

You need to change the logic of your application. Modern AJAX applications *must* continuously save the data that need saving or provide a visible way to launch the save, they can't wait for the window to be closing. And you have to manage your sessions life-cycle server-side without relying on the browser issuing a log-off.

Regarding the alert and Chrome, here's [an extract from the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload) :

> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to
>   window.showModalDialog(), window.alert(), window.confirm(), and
>   window.prompt() methods may be ignored during this event.

It's probable that more and more browsers will prevent this alert which is just painful most of the times.

Comment: do u mean to say that window.unload itself wont work ??? or just the alert part within window.unload wont work ?

Comment: actually i need to trigger log-off functionality while the window is getting closed ..

Comment: Inside the event handler you may (not 100% reliably) do small actions, like changing localStorage, you can't do an ajax call and you can't be sure you can make an alert.

Comment: And it makes no sense to trigger a log-off when the window is closing. You have to manage your sessions life-cycle server side without relying on the browser issuing a log-off.

Comment: ok.. i wil explain .. we have a funcionality such way that, while logging off, some details from the table would be deleted... this is working fine in IE and not in chrome. thats the problem ..not just session killing.. we perform some data deletion in table

Comment: This is a very bad architecture. You can't rely on the browser sending a log-off signal. Always assume the network or browser can disappear. This means for example your server must clean the sessions that weren't recently hit.